# Red Hat: using <atomic> compiles fine but linker can't find __atomic_store_16; what library?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors, redhat, stdatomic

I'm using `atomic<>` for the first time, and just as using `<thread>` requires you to link a thread library, it seems like using `<atomic>` wants you to do... something.  What?

```
> uname -a
Linux sdclxd00239 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 28 14:23:39 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu

> g++ Foo.cxx -g -o MsgQueueNoLock -pthread
/tmp/ccnGOKUG.o: In function `std::atomic<Ptr_T>::store(Ptr_T, std::memory_order)':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/atomic:239: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
/tmp/ccnGOKUG.o: In function `std::atomic<Ptr_T>::load(std::memory_order) const':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/atomic:250: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status>

g++ Foo.cxx -g -o Foo -pthread
/tmp/ccnGOKUG.o: In function `std::atomic<Ptr_T>::store(Ptr_T, std::memory_order)':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/atomic:239: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
/tmp/ccnGOKUG.o: In function `std::atomic<Ptr_T>::load(std::memory_order) const':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/atomic:250: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**UPDATE:** I need to use `-latomic` .  Fair enough!  However I can't find one I can actually use.

First I look under `/usr/lib`, and I see I have a simlink under `gcc/.../4.8.2` pointing to `gcc/.../4.8.5` ?!!?  I've never in my life seen an old version depend on a new version though the timestamp causes me to suspect either manual intervention by someone in the past, or a complicated history.

```
> l `find /usr/lib -name '*atomic*'`
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root 1379 Jul 13  2017 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sos/plugins/atomichost.pyo
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root 1379 Jul 13  2017 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sos/plugins/atomichost.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1672 Jul 13  2017 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sos/plugins/atomichost.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   40 Sep 22  2017 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libatomic.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   38 Sep 22  2017 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libatomic.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   44 Jul  3  2018 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libatomic.a -> ../../../i686-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libatomic.a
```

Something on the 'net suggested I might find joy under `/usr/local/lib` but in fact joy is not to be found:

```
> find /usr/local/lib -name '*atomic*'
>
```

The gcc actually installed is old (4.8.5) and I'm running 7.2.1 via the scl utility, which puts `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc` into the path.  Anticipating that the requisite lib was probably delivered with the gcc, I look at `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7` ... and like a bad dream the libatomic.a *again* is a symlink to a non-existent file.

```
> l `find /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/ -name '*atomic*'`
    :
    (headers elided)
    :
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40975 Aug 31  2017 /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/include/c++/7/atomic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    80 Aug 31  2017 /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libatomic.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1553 Oct  6  2017 /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/linux/atomic.stp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    40 Jul  3  2018 /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libatomic.a -> ../../../i686-redhat-linux/7/libatomic.a
```

So using `-L` options with every path I can think of based on what `find` found, here's all the errors:

```
> g++ MsgQueueNoLock.cxx -g -o MsgQueueNoLock -pthread -latomic
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find -latomic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> g++ MsgQueueNoLock.cxx -g -o MsgQueueNoLock -pthread -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2 -latomic
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libatomic.so.1.0.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> g++ MsgQueueNoLock.cxx -g -o MsgQueueNoLock -pthread -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32 -latomic
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libatomic.so.1.0.0
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libgcc.a when searching for libgcc.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> g++ MsgQueueNoLock.cxx -g -o MsgQueueNoLock -pthread -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32 -latomic
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libatomic.so when searching for -latomic
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: cannot find -latomic
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libgcc.a when searching for libgcc.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libatomic.a` is under a `/32` subdirectory, with a symlink pointing to `i686...`  That's useless (unless you're compiling obsolete 32-bit executables).  Finish installing gcc / build-essential packages or whatever RedHat calls them; your `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/` GCC install is broken.  Note that it can't even find its own `libgcc.a` or `libgcc_s.so` either!!  That's for internal GCC helper functions like `__int128` division which gcc always links, along with libc.

Comment: "it can't even find its own libgcc.a" -- it can find them fine, actually, in normal usage.  It's just that when I tried specifying these -L's, they take precedence, and there are (incorrect) libgcc.a's and so on in the -L directory that it is complaining about.  I'm trying to figure out how find all UNINSTALLED rpm packages that contain a libatomic.a or .so, but I have only figured out how to search INSTALLED packages, any idea @PeterCordes?

Comment: Oh I see, right that's because you used `-L/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32` which made it try 32-bit libraries.  Of course that's not going to work; you're compiling 64-bit code.  I re-added the redhat tag now that you've turned this back into a redhat-specific question about your GCC install that's missing libatomic.  TrentP commented under the answer that it's in the `libatomic` package, so you should install that.  (Or install it into your `/opt` GCC7 install?  Is that what RedHat makes you do to use a compiler that isn't super-old?)

Comment: btw, I suspected the `.../32/...` in the pathnames was a reference to 32-bit but being under `x86_64` was a counter-indication.

Comment: I think that's because the compiler is built with x86-64 as it's default target, and `-m32` 32-bit mode is an extra multi-arch that it supports.  CRT startup files (`.o`) and 32-bit libgcc need to go somewhere under there, and `/32` is where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample libatomic.c implementation here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=libatomic.c  Its compilation produces several warnings but ultimately produces an object file.

```
> gcc -c -o libatomic.o libatomic.c
libatomic.c:475:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function '__atomic_compare_exchange_1' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
 __atomic_compare_exchange_ ## SIZE   (I ## SIZE *mem, I ## SIZE *expect, I ## SIZE desired, int success, int failure)    \
 ^
libatomic.c:524:1: note: in expansion of macro 'ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE'
 ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE (1)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libatomic.c:475:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function '__atomic_compare_exchange_2' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
 __atomic_compare_exchange_ ## SIZE   (I ## SIZE *mem, I ## SIZE *expect, I ## SIZE desired, int success, int failure)    \
 ^
libatomic.c:537:1: note: in expansion of macro 'ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE'
 ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE (2)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libatomic.c:475:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function '__atomic_compare_exchange_4' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
 __atomic_compare_exchange_ ## SIZE   (I ## SIZE *mem, I ## SIZE *expect, I ## SIZE desired, int success, int failure)    \
 ^
libatomic.c:551:1: note: in expansion of macro 'ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE'
 ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE (4)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libatomic.c:475:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function '__atomic_compare_exchange_8' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
 __atomic_compare_exchange_ ## SIZE   (I ## SIZE *mem, I ## SIZE *expect, I ## SIZE desired, int success, int failure)    \
 ^
libatomic.c:565:1: note: in expansion of macro 'ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE'
 ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE (8)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libatomic.c:475:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function '__atomic_compare_exchange_16' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
 __atomic_compare_exchange_ ## SIZE   (I ## SIZE *mem, I ## SIZE *expect, I ## SIZE desired, int success, int failure)    \
 ^
libatomic.c:579:1: note: in expansion of macro 'ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE'
 ATOMIC_COMPARE_EXCHANGE (16)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ar rcs libatomic.a libatomic.o

> g++ Foo.cxx -g -o Foo-pthread -L. -latomic
```

Linking success: binary is created without error.  My application is too partially-written to judge whether it actually works though.

Even if this works, it's pretty clearly "not what you're supposed to have to do to get it to work."  So I'm not marking this as "the" answer, just leaving it for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

Someone that is building 64bit code in CentOS and needs `atomic` might stumble upon this article, so I just want to add that I actually had to install it as follows,

```
sudo yum install devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel
```

I do not know much about the library. I was just trying to compile `ponyc`, and I first needed to run the following commands,

```
yum install llvm-toolset-7
echo "source scl_source enable devtoolset-7 llvm-toolset-7" >> ~/.bashrc
```

There were some more modifications that I had to make to the CMakeLists.txt files but that would now be off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. `devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel` was all I needed, on top of `devtoolset-7`. Of course if you are using `devtoolset-9` you would get the corresponding package instead, but otherwise it's all the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case, this helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

To use 16-byte atomics with gcc you need `-latomic`

Comment: Thanks Anthony; curious how you figured this out?  I didn't see it in g++ docs, web search, doing nm -a on /usr/lib/*64*/*, etc. etc.

Comment: I've done a lot of development with multithreading and atomics using gcc ;) I can't remember how I first became aware of this aspect, it was a few years ago.

Comment: @SwissFrank: Just like `-lm` if you use any math.h functions, use `-latomic` if you use any `<atomic>` functions.  The difference is that many math library functions won't inline, but most stuff you use from `<atomic>` will be lock-free and inline so you don't normally actually need any functions from the shared library.  So you can go a long time before hitting a case where you actually do need `-latomic`.  GCC7 changed 16-byte atomics to not inline even with `-mcx16` (cmpxchg16b), and not to call them lock-free.  (Even though they actually are; only the earlier AMD64 were missing cmpxchg16b

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, but I'm not finding a libatomic.a or .so that is usable.  I'm amending my original question to include what I've tried, just a sec.

Comment: @SwissFrank: On my Arch Linux system, `/usr/lib/libatomic.so is owned by gcc-libs 9.1.0-2` according to `pacman` (Arch's equivalent of `rpm`).  On an Ubuntu system, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1` seems to be packaged in the `libatomic1` package, which gcc dev packages depend on.  And there are `.a` static versions of it in gcc directories, according to `locate libatomic`

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks again and I just edited my problem description above with all the sordid details.  This is a RedHat system at a new employer and I haven't figured out who that is.  "locate libatomic" is finding only the 5 libs I found with find, above.

Comment: libatomic is part of the `libatomic` package.  It doesn't appear to be required by gcc so it's entirely possible that it hasn't been installed.

Comment: @TrentP thanks!  I'm not an expert on rpm and I see how to find which INSTALLED package had a given file or filename, but how does one find an UNINSTALLED package that would supply it?  In other words, how could I have figured out that there is a libatomic package?

Comment: The rpm command only works locally.  To work with remote repositories use something like `dnf` (newer) or `yum` (older), depending on what distro you are using.  E.g., `dnf provides */libatomic.so.*`